# Add image while adding elements to a unordered list from another UL dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectable

When I click on the image which appears when hovered over a text, that element will be moved to another UL. I need the same image option as which is on the 1st list to delete it. I dont know how to add it dynamically.
Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance.

Image link is:

https://www.signaturecontrolsystems.com/Support/SmallRedX.gif

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/jquery_ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">       
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            #firstlist li:hover img {display: inline;}
            #firstlist li:hover { background: #CCF5CC; }
            #firstlist .ui-selected { background: #80B280; }
            #firstlist { list-style-type: none;}
            #firstlist li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.3em;}

            #seclist {list-style-type: none;}
            #seclist li {padding: 0.4em;}

            img {display:none;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table id="myTable" class= "table table-bordered">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-6 text-center success">
                    List 1
                </th>
                <th class="col-md-6 text-center success">
                    List 2
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td class="col-md-6">
                    <ul id="firstlist">
                        <li>Apple <img src="next.jpg" class = "list1"></li>
                        <li>Orange <img src="next.jpg" class = "list1"></li>
                        <li>Avacado <img src="next.jpg" class = "list1"></li>
                        <li>Banana <img src="next.jpg" class = "list1"></li>
                        <li>Mango <img src="next.jpg" class = "list1"></li>
                    <ul>    
                </td>
                <td class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class = "seclist" id = "seclist"> </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script>        
            $(function(){
                $( "#firstlist" ).selectable();
            });

            $(function() {
                $( "#seclist" ).selectable();
            });

            $(".list1").click(function() {
                var text = $(this).closest("li").text();
                $('<li />', {html: text}).appendTo('ul.seclist')
                $(this).unbind('click');
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to add image next to text in list 2 as it happens in list one. As the <li> are added dynamically i dont know how to add image next to the <li> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".list1").click(function() {
                var text = $(this).closest("li").text();
                $('<li/>', {html: text}).addClass("ui-selectee").appendTo('ul.seclist').append("<img src='cancel.jpg' class = 'list2 ui-selectee'/>");
                this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            });

            $('ul').on('click', '.list2', function(e) {
                $(this).parent('li').remove();

                var liTwo = $(this).closest("li").text();
                var listItems = $("#firstlist li");

                listItems.each(function(li) {
                    var liOne = $(this).text();
                    if(liTwo.match(liOne)){
                        document.getElementById(liOne.trim()).style.visibility = 'visible';
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: What event do you want to bind to that button and what do want to do on that event ?

Comment: No its like this. When i click that button it must not allow the user to click it again. And when clicked once the text will be moved to the other list. And when user click on the image on the other list(which is to remove any element added) that text must be removed from list 2 and the unbind(diabled) image must be available to use like before. So that user can slect it again and after one click it diables and this process can repeat. If you want i can update the current code im working on

Comment: Sorry ! but not getting you clearly ! What do you want to do after the item is added into the right-side list (after you click on the button on the item in the left-side list) ?  Do you want to remove that item from the right-side list when click on the button ?

Comment: I have edited your post sir. There are two functions. One to add the selcted text from list 1 to list 2 with an image. Then the other to remove that elemnt when clicked on the image. And when clicking the image on list 1 that clicked image must be bind and when i remove items from list 2 image corresponding the item in list one must be able to click once again. Is it clear. Im sorry im bad in eng.

Comment: forgot to mention, i used "visibility to do what i wanted". But instead is it possible to do with bind and unbind so that image will be there but when user click on it there wont be no function done.

Answer (score 1):

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/wcEt5/1/)

Instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) try using [***`.html()`***](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Replaced

```
var text = $(this).closest("li").text();
```

to

```
var text = $(this).closest("li").html();
```

---

According to documentation

> [***`.text()`***](http://api.jquery.com/text/):- Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.
>
> [***`.html()`***](http://api.jquery.com/html/):- Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

In simpler words, ***the result of the `.text()` method is a string whereas the result of `.html()` method is the HTML content of the first matched element***.